# Регистр имен файлов Windows и Mercurial

Tags: windows, контроль-версий, mercurial

Есть такая проблема. Сайт разрабатывается под Windows, а сервер веб-сервисом крутится под Linux. Использую систему контроля версий **mercurial**.

Можно ли под Windows его как-нибудь настроить, чтобы изменение регистра имён файлов тоже считалось изменением файла (сделать регистрозависимым)?

Comment: мне кажется проще всего договориться, чтобы все файлы были lowecase. Иначе огребете проблем - 100%

Comment: @gecube, там тоже не всё гладко, если я хочу работать c composer и psr-0 или psr-4

Comment: @gecube, как иногда бывает сложно договариваться об отсутствии верблюжестьи с некоторыми.. хм.. начинающими :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из ртутного руководства, [глава 7, параграф 7](https://bacher09.org/hgbook/ru/html/file-names-and-pattern-matching.html#sec:names:case):

(здесь речь идёт об исправлении проблем с регистром имён файлов. но понятно, что Mercurial просто не заточен на решение подобных вопросов, считает их как возможные конфликты, и вообще: *система хранилищ Mercurial регистронезависима*)

> Если вы используете Windows или Mac в среде, где кто-то использует
>   Linux или Unix, и Mercurial сообщает о проблемах с регистром, когда вы
>   пытаетесь сделать hg update или hg merge, процедура исправления этого
>   очень проста.
>
> Просто найдите ближайшую машину с Linux или Unix, клонируйте на нее
>   репозиторий и используйте команду hg rename для изменения имени на
>   какое-то другое, так чтобы конфликта не было. Сохраните свои изменения
>   (hg commit), сделайте hg pull или hg push в ваш Windows или MacOS
>   репозитарий и hg update на ревизию без конфликта.
>
> Список изменений с конфликтом регистра останется в истории вашего
>   проекта и вы все еще будете не в состоянии выполнить hg update вашей
>   рабочей директории к этому набору изменений в Windows или MacOS, но вы
>   сможете продолжить разработку.